# AMI - Unable to start httpd after adding SSL

Tags: httpd

In order to install SSL on my Lightsail instance (with AMI), I followed the instructions provided here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

Once I saved and tried to restart the web server, the httpd server won't start. This is what I get:

```
[ec2-user@ run] service httpd start
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted. [ FAILED ]
```

Tried with Sudo;

```
[ec2-user@ip- ~]$ sudo service httpd start Starting httpd: [FAILED]
```

I tried going to the directory and find the file, but it's not there.

```
[root@ip httpd]# ls -l
total 4
drwx------ 2 apache apache 4096 Jan 19 16:56 htcacheclean
```

I searched various forms, including Stack but was unable to find help that worked. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You *must* start the service as root (e.g. using sudo). It's probably already running, so kill it with `sudo pkill httpd`. If it still won't start, try `sudo httpd -DFOREGROUND` and look for errors in the output.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but that did not help. I tried both the commands with sudo. The http is not running.

    [root@ip- httpd]# service httpd status
    httpd is stopped

Comment: And errors in `sudo httpd -DFOREGROUND` ?

Comment: No errors,
`[ec2-user@ip- ~]$ sudo httpd -DFOREGROUND  
[ec2-user@ip- ~]$`

Comment: This is what the error_log says;
'[Tue Apr 11 13:40:11.867993 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 5377] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Apr 11 13:40:11.868853 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5377] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed'

Comment: @WaqasTariq, can you check this file `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid` permissions? If you don't have enough privileges, change them accordingly. If after changing permissions face the same issue, delete the file and start httpd process. Hope this helps!

Comment: I was able to fix this issue. I reexamined /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and found out that I had commented out 'SSLCertificateKeyFile' and the path on 'SSLCertificateKeyFile' to the private key was incorrect. Fixed it and the server restarted successfully.

Thank you all for your help.

PS: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: @WaqasTariq You should post the answer as an answer, and then you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. I reexamined /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and found out that I had commented out 'SSLCertificateKeyFile' and the path on 'SSLCertificateKeyFile' to the private key was incorrect. Fixed it and the server restarted successfully. Thank you all for your help.